# Given a set of boolean columns how can I get the top 5 columns with the most amount of true values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, group-concat

```
CREATE TABLE test(
column1 BOOLEAN,
column2 BOOLEAN,
column3 BOOLEAN
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (true, false, true);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (true, false, true);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (true, false, false);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (true, false, false);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (true, false, true);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (true, false, true);
```

I am looking for a result where I get

Highest Number of Trues in descending order: Column1, Column3, Column2.
In specific, I need the name of the columns. Any idea on how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to get a resultset from your table with only 2 columns: the name of each column as a string and its value.
Then use 2 levels of aggregation and with `GROUP_CONCAT()` get the result that you want:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY total DESC) result
FROM (
  SELECT name, SUM(col) total
  FROM (
    SELECT 'column1' name, column1 col FROM test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'column2', column2 FROM test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'column3', column3 FROM test
  ) t
  GROUP BY name
) t;
```

If you want the column names in different rows:

```
SELECT name, SUM(col) total
FROM (
  SELECT 'column1' name, column1 col FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'column2', column2 FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'column3', column3 FROM test
) t
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f5dff1a54d4b00bb5562236a0ff9ad4).

If there are actually more columns and you want the names of the top 5 columns, replace:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY total DESC)
```

with:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY total DESC), ',', 5)
```

and:

```
ORDER BY total DESC
```

with:

```
ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Question about your solution, it works perfectly. And I am trying to understand how you selected name in the outer query. And could you tell me what the line 3: SELECT 'column1' name, column1 col is doing? I don't quite understand the syntax.

Comment: @ss2 check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a1610c34757a48f17f5b6318c3c1ce7 the inner query returns a resultset with 2 columns name and col that contains the column's name and each of its values. Then all that is needed is aggregation by name.